# Can I get the index from Knockout Foreach Template and pass to Html.EditorFor?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

Using MVC 4, I am looking for a simple way to combine a knockout template and an EditorFor.  I almost have what I'm looking for:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name:'cover', foreach: StockItems }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="cover">                  
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.StockItems[0].Name, "MyTemplate",
                     new { htmlAttributes = new 
                         { data_bind = "value: $data.Name")
```

In the editor template I can bind the value from the knockout template:

```
@model KnockOut.Models.StockItem   
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, ViewData["htmlAttributes"])
```

This works pretty well and is almost a nice simple solution that meets my need.  I have some very simple JavaScript to control adding, removing and posting JSON back to the server.

The bit I don't like is that I hard code 0 here: m.StockItems[0].Name, which leads to the name and id attributes being generated as:

```
id="StockItems_0__Name" name="StockItems[0].Name"
```

for each item I have.  I could do something like use `attr`: for id, name and whatever else and use `$index()` to rename the accordingly:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.StockItems[0].Name, "MyTemplate", 
                  new { htmlAttributes =new { data_bind = 
                          "value: $data.Name,     
                           attr:id:='StockIten_'+$index()+'.Name'")
```

I think probably that I need a more sophisticated EditorFor and use a C# @foreach() instead of the Knockout foreach and template and what I'm about to ask is not possible.

However, is there anyway I can somehow get the index from the Knockout template to the EditorFor?

Of course, I'm also very interested on seeing a better way to tackle the whole problem.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have some customised MVC View provider which allows you to implement Knockout in your views, *i.e.* on the server?

Comment: not to my knowledge.

Comment: Then I can't see how you could possibly pass a value from the client-side view-model back in time to when the server was rendering that HTML which the view-model is now operating upon.

Comment: Matthew Osborn is right and you can't, but I'm just wondering if you absolutely *want* to use `EditorFor` to begin with.

My philosophy on the whole thing is that Razor and JS are two vastly different tools that have vastly different purposes -- separated so never the twain shall meet.  It's obviously not *wrong* to use the two together like this, but I'm just wondering if you want to use Razor to generate inputs in the first place -- why not go "whole-hog" and use that JavaScript you mentioned to handle submit/response behavior with Knockout.

Answer (score 0):

Html.EditorFor runs server side and knockout runs client site, so no you cannot.